# Swift 3 : How to convert struct to Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, serialization

I have a `struct` as follows

```
struct UserInfo
{
    var userId : Int
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
}
```

How do I serialize an instance of `UserInfo` to type `Parameters`?

```
var user = UserInfo(userId: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Skew")

// Convert user to Parameters for Alamofire
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just implement a `dictionaryRepresentation` computed variable or function:

```
struct UserInfo {
    var userId : Int

    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String

    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "userId" : userId,
            "firstName" : firstName,
            "lastName" : lastName
        ]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var user = UserInfo(userId: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Skew")
let userDict = user.dictionaryRepresentation
```

Comment: This is a good option. What is the easiest way to convert an object array to a dictionary in this approach?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) library. Although it's main purpose is to use it with [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/), it actually does what you need - converts the value into dictionary `[String: Any]`.

Your model would look the following:

```
struct UserInfo: Codable {
    var userId : Int
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
}
```

And then you would convert it to dictionary in the following way:

```
import CodableFirebase

let model: UserInfo // here you will create an instance of UserInfo
let dict: [String: Any] = try! FirestoreEncoder().encode(model)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly pass struct as parameter. You need to convert your struct into `[String:Any]`. I have added a new variable description that converts your content to dictionary

```
struct UserInfo
{
    var userId : Int
    var firstname : String
    var lastname : String


    var description:[String:Any] {
        get {
            return ["userId":userId, "firstname": self.firstname, "lastname": lastname] as [String : Any]
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage is

```
var user = UserInfo(userId: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Skew")

// Convert user to Parameters for Alamofire
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: user.description)
```

Comment: How does this differ from @alexburtnik's answer?

Comment: Seems like no difference. Both users tried to post similar answer at same time from different locations :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to make parameters to be sent as a POST request then it should take a dictionary format as follows:

```
let userDict = ["userId" : user.userId, "firstname" : user.firstname, "lastname" : user.lastname]
```

This should work as "parameters" for your networking

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 you can use Decodable/Codable Struct

Comment: Care to elaborate how?